# Is there a shorter way to write this FXML extract?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

The layout is as such:

[image]

What is of interest is the upper part of the window; it is a `GridPane` filled with labels and I have added padding, but...

Well, the problem is obvious:

```
            <GridPane gridLinesVisible="false">
                <padding>
                    <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0"/>
                </padding>
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                    <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                </rowConstraints>

                <!-- First column -->
                <Label text="Date:" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="0">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="parseDate" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>

                <Label text="Total parse time:" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="0">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="totalParseTime" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>

                <Label text="Parse tree depth:" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="0">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="treeDepth" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>

                <Label text="Number of rules:" GridPane.rowIndex="3"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="nrRules" GridPane.rowIndex="3"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>

                <!-- Second column -->
                <Label text="Total rule invocations:" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="totalInvocations" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>

                <Label text="Successful rules:" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="totalSuccess" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>

                <Label text="Global success rate:" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="totalSuccessRate" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5.0" bottom="5.0" left="5.0"
                            right="5.0"/>
                    </padding>
                </Label>
            </GridPane>
```

In order to achieve what I wanted I had to add a padding to each and every `Label` :/

I have walked through the javadoc of `GridPane` and couldn't find another way than what I have right now, but I'm sure this other, shorter and more maintainable way exists.

So, what is this shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding [VGap](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setVgap%28double%29) and [HGap](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHgap%28double%29) to the `Gridpane`, instead of adding Padding to every node in it.

> hgapProperty - The width of the horizontal gaps between columns.
>
> vgapProperty - The height of the vertical gaps between rows.